# Specify custom powerpoint theme in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint

I am using R markdown to create a presentation. Here's a sample code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "April 2018"
date: "4/9/2019"
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r pressure, fig.width=30, fig.asp=0.618, 
   out.width="200%"}
plot(pressure)
```
````

I want to apply a custom template that is specified by my organisation. How do I specify the custom theme? I read online that this can be specified by:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "April 2018"
date: "4/9/2019"
output: powerpoint_presentation:
  reference_doc: my_theme.pptx 
---
```

But how does this work? Where do I have to store the my_theme.pptx file?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598415/r-markdown-powerpoint-slide-customization) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you don't need this answer now, but just in reference for all of the guyz who were seeking for the answer like me.

Go to >> R\win-library\version e.g. 4.0\officer >>> paste your custom template on this path.

It will work